# How to implement swipe back between fragment?

Tags: android, swipe, android-dialogfragment, swipe-gesture

I have a full screen dialog fragment and i want to swipe back from my dialog to last activity , and I just find a library that swipe back in activity. Does any one have a suggestion?!

Comment: I guess what you want is a TabLayout working with swipes from out of the screen only

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it using Gestures [Capturing touch events for an Activity or View](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html)

> To intercept touch events in an Activity or View, override the
> onTouchEvent() callback.

and then check for swipe move, in which case you call `finish()` or whatever suits you.